# Compilar multiplos arquivos

Tags: c#

Eu tenho 3 aquivos: client.exe, client.dll, client.dat.

Queria compilar eles em um único exe como o Molebox faz.

Pesquisei por *Binder Files*, tentei colocar o *resourcer* do meu aplicativo, porem sempre tem que extrair os arquivos para usá-los.

Procuro uma forma de compilar e não precisar extrair para usar.

Comment: O http://www.evalaze.de/en/home/ possui uma versão Free

Comment: Por que você quer transformar tudo em 1 único exe?